# Dual Canadian and British citizen with only a British passport

Tags: air-travel, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, canadian-citizens, dual-nationality

I am both a British citizen and a Canadian citizen I live in the UK and only have a British passport. Will being Canadian with proof of Canadian citizenship alter the requirement to obtain an ESTA before travelling to the USA from the UK on a UK pasport?

Comment: Apparently, [you do need a passport](http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas/information-for-canadians.html) or NEXUS card so it might be easier to enter as a British citizen with ESTA. But then I guess you need to follow the rules of the visa waiver program.

Comment: Similar question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21963/canadian-citizen-with-british-passport-visiting-usa

Comment: What *proof of Canadian citizenship* do you have?

Answer (score 6):

The [US ESTA website](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1094/~/do-i-need-to-apply-for-esta) says explicitly:

> citizens of Canada **who are traveling with a Canadian passport** do not need an ESTA. *(emphasis mine)*

I would deduce that without a Canadian passport you will need to go through ESTA.

I'm also a dual British/Canadian citizen, resident in Canada, and I found it well worthwhile to get a Canadian passport precisely to avoid this sort of thing at the US border. But I go to the US pretty frequently.